# Using directive does not work in Visual Studio 2015 C#

Tags: c#, using

In my C# Project for an Outlook AddIn I've the typical namespacing implemented with the using directive (done by IDE):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

But when I use a method / namespace / struct (whatever) which should be in a namespace specified above, I receive an error:

[image: Code Screenshot]

I only can use fully qualified methods, like

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("OK");
```

With, for example,

```
Forms.MessageBox.Show("NN");
```

I receive Error CS0103

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have imported `System.Windows.Forms`, not `System.Windows`. So you need to use `MessageBox.Show("NN")`, not `Forms.MessageBox.Show("NN")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you may notice, you included

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

thus you don't need to add Forms for Messagebox
you ll also notice that System.Windows.Forms is greyed out

Answer (score 1):

You have included the `.Forms` in your using directive. You can just use `MessageBox.Show`

Comment: Right. I used "Forms.MessageBox... although a already added using System.Windows.Forms; .   
System.Windows works not. Maybe because .Windows is a namespace?

Comment: You are right. I have corrected my answer.

A namespace is just where a set of objects belong. Think of a namespace as like a toolbox. You have one toolbox for just your "screwdrivers" So it would be like `Using System.Screwdrivers;` and then you could call `PhillipsHead.Turn(180):`